# Tango Unity SDK - TangoPoseSupport and coordinate frames

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm trying to wrap my head around the various transforms between the coordinate frames, so I can validate that my AD frame and SOS frame are where I want them to be in relation to my world origin.

in TangoSupport.TangoPoseToWorldTransform, the DEVICE_T_UNITY_CAMERA matrix has a row2 that looks like (0, 1, -1, 0). The docs here (https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/coordinate-systems) explain that we're moving from left-to-right handed and we need to swap axis direction in various cases, but I'd expect each matrix row to be a single value (positive or negative)?  Is row2 not introducing a shear? If this is expected, any chance we can get the docs updated to explain it?

Answer (score 0):

That is bug has been fixed in newer release, it should be (0, 0, -1, 0).